# Undefined index: URL [APP/View/Clients/index.ctp, line 90]

Tags: php, cakephp, notice

I have been asked to work on aplication someone else has created with cakePHP. I am new to cakePHP.The application shows the following errors

```
Notice(8):

    if(isset($client[0]) && $client[0]['contacts']['type_of']==3 && $var=='clients_with_contacts' && $this->Paginator->current()==1){
                                echo '<td style="background:lightblue">'.$client[0]['Client'][$field].'</td>';

include - APP/View/Clients/index.ctp, line 90
View::_evaluate() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 947
View::_render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 909
View::render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 471
Controller::render() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 948
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 194
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 162
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 112
```

There is a ton of code.If you can think of anything let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to check for variables '$var' and '$client[0]['contacts']['type_of']' in the condition, like this:

```
if(isset($client[0]['contacts']['type_of']) && $client[0]['contacts']['type_of']==3 && isset($var) && $var=='clients_with_contacts' && $this->Paginator->current()==1){

echo '<td style="background:lightblue">'.$client[0]['Client'][$field].'</td>';

}
```

Comment: Ι Check the specific point of my table(`if(isset($client[0]['Client']['url']))`) and shows that there is no

Comment: Try to check this other variable: '$client[0]['Client'][$field]'. Like: 'if(...) {if(isset($client[0]['Client'][$field])){ echo ...;}}'

Answer (score 0):

In ClientsController, check $client, and $var have been transferred correctly through :

```
$this->set ('client', $variable1);
$this->set ('var', $variable2);
```

or

```
$this->set (array ('client' => $variable1, 'var' => $variable2));
```

If so, check all fields for `$client` array exists too.
Also in your codes, if statement missed a `}` too.

Comment: we write 
`var_dump($client)`

Comment: I see, a bit more source code maybe helpful to find  what's wrong, if you dump $client and it's fine, well...I have no idea what's wrong with your code

Comment: As it's undefined index, it does suggest that some index of your array is misused.

Comment: Do you notice $client[0]['Client'][$field]? if $field is a invalid index for $client, could raise this exception. As $field is variable, and it changed in context.